# Click() and Toggle() - error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a grasp on the click() and toggle() methods, but when I try to implement them it appears to be "stripping" the clicked class off my page and running the code. Because the original class is stripped off my page, I can't click() it again to toggle() it.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've looked this up many times and tried various sample codes and all seem to give me the same "stripping" effect as it appears to peel my class off the page and to the left. Also there are various cases I'll need to use IDs which is why I cannot use the addClass() removeClass() methods.

Here is my code (I left the CSS because it's easier to see the "stripping" effect that I'm referring to when there is a background and not just text):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <head>
    <title>Header</title>
    <style>
    body {
      background: black;
      color: white;
      }
    div {
     background: blue; 
    }
    .adventure{
      position: absolute;
      top: 22px;
      left: 0px;
    }
    .solarSystem{
      position: absolute;
      top: 44px;
      left: 0px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="adventure">Choose Own Adventure</div>
      <div class="solarSystem">Solar System</div>
  </body>
      <script>
      $(".adventure").click(
      function(){
      $('.adventure').toggle(function () {
    $(".solarSystem").css({top: "150px"});
}, function () {
    $(".solarSystem").css({top: "250px"});
});
});
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I've spent entirely too long troubleshooting this with no luck. :( Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a `toggle()` function inside a `click()` function probably doesn't do what you think, and that version of `toggle()` is removed in newer versions of jQuery as well

You could just create your own toggle functionality

```
$(".adventure").on('click', function(){
    var flag = $(this).data('flag');

    $(".solarSystem").css({top: (flag ? "250px" : "150px")});

    $(this).data('flag', !flag);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cyDW/)

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to do, thanks! Is there any way to revert it to the default css value rather than setting a 2nd value manually? Basically the first click would apply the new css and the second click would return it to the default setting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this?

```
<Style>
.big-top {top:250px;}
.little-top {top:2150px;}
</style>

<script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".adventure").click(
      function(){
            $(".solarSystem").toggleClass("big-top");

       }); 
      $(".solarSystem").click(
      function(){
            $(".adventure").toggleClass("little-top");

       });
});
</script>
```